# Diagnosing Based on Finding The Probability

Tags: probability

"It is known that 86% of persons with insomnia also have a problem with fatigue.  Dr. Delgado's patient Bob reports no problem with fatigue.  Should Dr. Delgado decide that Bob has insomnia?"  I don't need the answer please I would just like to know how to work it out.

Comment: @Latifah Welcome to MSE! I think it's a little hard to diagnose what you're asking for here; can you give us a bit of context for what you're looking for? There are a range of reasonable answers one could give to this kind of question, from conceptual to computational. What should an answer to your question look like, and what tools might it use?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thank you for responding! Part (b) to the question is "If further testing reveals that Bob does have insomnia, explain how the previous decision in part (a) of this problem could have occured."  Other students in class were stumped because we came up with different answers, I'm guessing the tutor just wants justification but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

> Should Dr. Delgado diagnose Bob with insomnia?

I'd say Dr. Delgado really doesn't have much information one way or another. What's happening here is a difficulty in making inverse statements. The $86\%$ figure is of the form $\mathbb P(\text{fatigue} \mid \text{insomnia})$, and the goal is to say something about $\mathbb P(\text{insomnia} \mid \text{no fatigue})$, which is basically impossible to do in the abstract.

I'll try to illustrate what's going on with two situations. Consider first a grouping of $161$ people as follows:
$$ \begin{array}{c|cc|c}
  & \text{insomnia} & \text{no insomnia} & \text{total}\\ \hline
\text{fatigue} & 86 & 60 & 146 \\
\text{no fatigue} & 14 & 1 & 15 \\
\hline
\text{total} & 100 & 61 & 161
\end{array}$$
If you tell me someone has insomnia, you're telling me they're in the leftmost column; then, the probability that they have fatigue is $86/100 = 86\%$, as desired. Now, if you tell me someone has no fatigue, you're saying they're in the bottom *row*; the chance that they have insomnia is quite high ($14/15,$ or about $93\%$).

Here's another situation with a different $161$ people:
$$ \begin{array}{c|cc|c}
  & \text{insomnia} & \text{no insomnia} & \text{total}\\ \hline
\text{fatigue} & 86 & 1 & 87 \\
\text{no fatigue} & 14 & 60 & 74 \\
\hline
\text{total} & 100 & 61 & 161
\end{array}$$
Notice that just like above, we can say that $\mathbb P(\text{fatigue} \mid \text{insomnia}) = 0.86$. But this time, $\mathbb P(\text{insomnia} \mid \text{no fatigue}) = 14/74 \approx 19\%$.

This also hopefully gives some ideas of how you might respond to (b). Without knowing something about the overall rates of insomnia, and how insomnia and fatigue relate to one another, you really just don't have much information to go on.